# Error message - "closing bracket expected" when initializing a list

Tags: syntax-error, netlogo

I have defined a turtles-own list called color-affinity. Each of the 14 entries in this list is composed of a named netlogo color and a corresponding random number up to but not including 5.

I am trying to initialize this list in the setup procedure by calling the function: setup-turtle-color-affinity.

I'm working on Netlogo 6.1 (the latest version). The code is below.

```
turtles-own [
  color-affinity
]

...
..
.

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles population
  setup-turtle-color-affinity
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end

...
..
.

to setup-turtle-color-affinity
  ask turtles
  [ setup-color-affinity ]
end

to setup-color-affinity
  [
   ; Here, I want to set up the list so that each turtle gets a random named netlogo color and a corresponding random "affinity" score of up to 5. However, whenever I try this (and I've tried various combinations of syntax) it gives me an error saying "closing bracket expected".
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may need a little more detail to get a useful answer- for example, how your color list is set up? In Netlogo, the color names read simply as numbers- `grey` is 5, `red` is 15, etc. What kind of format are you after for `color-affinity`?

If you're after a list of list pairs for each turtle, where each pair is a color value and the affinity value, maybe something like this could work for you:

```
turtles-own [
  color-affinity
]

to setup
  ca

  let color-values ( range 5 145 10 )

  crt 5 [
    set color-affinity map [ c -> list c ( random 4 + 1 ) ] color-values
    show color-affinity
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Output:

```
(turtle 1): [[5 4] [15 3] [25 2] [35 4] [45 2] [55 1] [65 2] [75 1] [85 2] [95 3] [105 3] [115 1] [125 3]]
(turtle 3): [[5 2] [15 2] [25 2] [35 1] [45 2] [55 4] [65 4] [75 4] [85 3] [95 2] [105 1] [115 2] [125 2]]
(turtle 2): [[5 2] [15 4] [25 1] [35 1] [45 1] [55 4] [65 3] [75 2] [85 4] [95 1] [105 4] [115 4] [125 2]]
(turtle 0): [[5 1] [15 1] [25 3] [35 4] [45 4] [55 1] [65 4] [75 2] [85 1] [95 4] [105 1] [115 1] [125 1]]
(turtle 4): [[5 3] [15 3] [25 4] [35 4] [45 2] [55 2] [65 4] [75 1] [85 2] [95 3] [105 1] [115 4] [125 3]]
```

**Edit:**

I don't know of a way to automatically pull the color names (not to say there isn't one!)- you may have to do something like this `table` extension approach:

```
extensions [ table ]

globals [ color-table ]

to setup-color-table
  set color-table table:make
  let color-names [ 
    "gray" "red" "orange" "brown" "yellow" 
    "green" "lime" "turquoise" "cyan" "sky"
    "blue" "violet" "magenta" "pink" 
  ]
  let color-values ( range 5 145 10 )
  ( foreach color-values color-names [
    [ cv cn ] ->
    table:put color-table cv cn 
    ]
  )

  show table:get color-table 15
  show table:get color-table 65
  show table:get color-table 115
end
```

Output:

```
observer: "red"
observer: "lime"
observer: "violet"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm good with colors as numbers as long as I can extract the color names if I need them.

Comment: @Joebevo - You bet! To do that I think you may have to manually code it- see one approach in my edits.